# Django, getting access to parent's fields and method in Many to One relation

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have the below example for demonstration only, the relationship between the authors and books is one to many, each book can be written by one author only.

Let's say I have created a record for the author, and then created a book written by that author. When I want to update the Book's details, I would like to get the author age as well, and getting access to any filed of `Author` model in book template.

`{{form.author}}` will return the author name, I tried `{{form.author.age}}` 
 and  `{{form.author.find_age}}` without success.

My real example involves a formset of books, but I thought to make it simple as a single book as in the below will be easier for getting an answer.

**Model:**

```
class Author(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
  age = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1, default=3.0, blank = True )

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name   

  def find_age(self):
    return self.age     

class Book(models.Model):
  author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
  title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
  publish = models.CharField(max_length=300)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

**View:**

```
class BookCreate(CreateView):
   model = Book
   fields = '__all__'
   success_url = reverse_lazy('books-list')

class BookUpdate(UpdateView):
   model = Book
   success_url = reverse_lazy('books-list')
   fields = '__all__'    

class AuthorCreate(CreateView):
   model = Author
   fields = '__all__'
   success_url = reverse_lazy('authors-list')

class AuthorUpdate(UpdateView):
   model = Author
   success_url = reverse_lazy('authors-list')
   fields = '__all__'
```

**template:**

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    {{form}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the model instance associated with the form using `form.instance`

```
{{form.instance.author.age}}
```

Comment: I lost 2 days for missing "instance."!! Thank you Satendra.